# AccessDenied when open uploaded Image AWS S3 URL on Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm using React Native to upload image to AWS S3. I've upload successfully but the url of its denied then paste into Browser.

I've tried many format url and also s3.getSignedUrl (but I got other error: NoSuckKey, SignatureDoesNotMatch)

`Function to upload image to AWS S3`

```
  const uploadImageToS3 = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(photo);
      const blob = await response.blob();

      // Upload the image directly to S3 with public-read ACL
      const result = await Storage.put(uuid.v4(), blob, {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        level: 'public',
        bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      });

      console.log('Image uploaded successfully', result.key);

      const s3Link = `https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/${result.key}`;
      console.log('JSON: ', s3Link);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR UPLOADING FILE: ', error);
    }
  };
```

`Others way I've tried with S3.getSignedUrl`

```
  const pathToImageFile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(photo);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const result = await Storage.put(uuid.v4(), blob, {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        level: 'public',
        bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      });
      console.log('Image uploaded successfully', result.key);

      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${result.key}.jpeg`,
        Expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      };

      const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
      console.log('URL: ', url);

      // parseUrl(`https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${Key}`)
      const s3Link = `https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/${result.key}`;
      console.log('JSON: ', s3Link);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR UPLOADING FILE: ', error);
    }
  };
```

`S3`

```
  const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  });

  const s3 = new S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
    credentials,
  });
```

`My full code`

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {Camera} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
import {Storage} from 'aws-amplify';
import {BUCKET_NAME, MY_BUCKET_URL} from '../utils/contanst';
import {S3} from 'aws-sdk';
import {ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} from '../PrivateKey';

const VisionCamera = () => {
  const cameraPermission = Camera.requestCameraPermission();
  useEffect(() => {
    cameraPermission.then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }, []);

  const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  });

  const s3 = new S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
    credentials,
  });

  const devices = Camera.getAvailableCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.find(d => d.position === 'back');

  const camera = useRef(null);
  const [isTakingPhoto, setIsTakingPhoto] = useState(false);
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);

  const takingPhoto = async () => {
    if (camera.current == null) return;
    const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
    console.log('photo', `file://${photo.path}`);
    setPhoto(`file://${photo.path}`);
    setIsTakingPhoto(false);
  };

  const pathToImageFile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(photo);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const result = await Storage.put(uuid.v4(), blob, {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        level: 'public',
        bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      });
      console.log('Image uploaded successfully', result.key);

      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${result.key}.jpeg`,
        Expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      };

      const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
      console.log('URL: ', url);

      // parseUrl(`https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${Key}`)
      const s3Link = `https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/${result.key}`;
      console.log('JSON: ', s3Link);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR UPLOADING FILE: ', error);
    }
  };

  if (device == null) return <NoCameraDeviceError />;
  return (
    <>
      {isTakingPhoto ? (
        <>
          <Camera
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            device={device}
            isActive={true}
            photo={true}
            ref={camera}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btnTakingPhoto}
            onPress={() => takingPhoto()}>
            <Text>Take Photo</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsTakingPhoto(true)}>
              <Text>Taking Photo</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Image source={{uri: photo}} style={styles.image} />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pathToImageFile()}>
              <Text>Upload Photo</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default VisionCamera;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnTakingPhoto: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

**`Here my policies of IAM AWS`**

[List Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTQpf.png)

[JSON Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCsF.png)

Comment: A URL of the form `https://mybucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dog.png` only works if that object is public.

Comment: Does bucket have Default Encryption enabled?

Comment: where can I find it, my current bucket's access is: Objects can be public

Answer (score 0):

I gave up to get the url after uploaded.

Then I tried to get the URL by providing KEY of Image and it worked.

```
const getImageUrlByKey = async () => {
imageKey = 'MY_IMAGE_KEY';
try {
  const url = await Storage.get(imageKey, {
    level: 'public',
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  });
  console.log('URL for', imageKey, ':', url)

  // return url;
} catch (error) {
  console.log('ERROR GETTING IMAGE URL: ', error);
  return null;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

OMG it worked
I must change the policy script into the `permissions tab of bucket not into IAM Polic`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1Tu0yKmDKU&ab_channel=BeABetterDev

for more information